# How to monitor internet data usage for different gateways?

Tags: networking, monitoring, gateway

I have multiple gateways for using internet and I switch between them a lot. For example:

```
gateway_1: 192.168.1.1
gateway_2: 192.168.1.100
```

Is there any utility available that can monitor internet data used when using each gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Try vnstat

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
vnstat --help
```

Hope this helps :)